# Insertion sort algorithm modifying output

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I have a working simple insertion sort algorithm written in Python. What I'm trying to do is take the output and put it in a new list without altering the original input list. I've been stuck on trying to figure out how to do this and maybe I'm just overthinking it, but I thought I would see if anyone could help. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import sys
import random

def RandomArray(n, max):
    A = []
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        v = random.randint(1, max+1)
        if v not in A:
            A.append(v)
            i = i + 1
    return A

A = RandomArray(10,100)
print(A)

def InsertionSort(A):
    element = 1
    for element in range(0, (len(A))):
        w = A[element]
        j = element - 1
        while (j >= 0) & (A[j] > w):
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            j = j - 1
        A[j+1] = w
    return A

print(InsertionSort(A))
```

Comment: You are explicitly mutating the input array - if you don't want that to affect the original, either pass a copy (`InsertionSort(A[:])`) or refactor the function accordingly. Note that functions that mutate their inputs should return `None` by convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the list in your sorting function, a simple solution with existing solution would be deepcopy the list, before mutating it.

```
import copy

def InsertionSort(A):
    A = copy.deepcopy(A) # or A = A[:] might work as well in this case
    ...
    return A
```

As an extra advice, the naming conventions you are using are not pythonic. Function names should be snake cased instead of Pascal cased (I have kept the same just for consistency).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't realize it would be that easy and that there is already a module for copying